# How should I organize a 3-day Arduino beginners course?

Tags: arduino-uno

I will be teaching Arduino during a fair in my university, and the school gave me 3 afternoons to teach Arduino to Engineering students. Now I am looking for ideas on how to organize this course, and any help would be very nice.

Comment: Alphabetically (case sensitive).

Comment: This question is being flagged as too broad, and I don't blame them. This isn't a site for suggesting a syllabus for a course. Good luck with the fair, I hope it goes well, but questions here need to be more focussed. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). There doesn't seem to be a problem to be solved, as such.

Comment: Introduction, Blink, Serial, ADC, servos, more LEDs, I2C sensors / libraries, (WiFi with ESP?)...  You can pick some Starter Kit Manual for instpiration.

Comment: Good point @NickGammon. I would also question if the OP needs to ask this question are they qualified to teach the class. I am not trying to be mean, but I know the following to be true: to know how to do something is one thing, to teach it, is another. You need to know all about AVR and c/c++. You need to know the material inside and out.  However you may be prepared to do so. Either way, good luck.

Comment: well, I do know the stuff, as I am graduating from Control Engineering, and I am a teacher on other subjects already, so I was mainly wondering if there was any shortcut anyone more experienced could give me. I'll plan a little bit more and when my question becomes more specific I can edit it. Also, I couldn't find any tags for education, teaching, etc, so maybe that's an area not discussed much around here. Or I didn't look up in a proper fashion. Thanks, anyway!